# There are more people that have done ... or who have done?

Tags: who-that

I know that *that* is used for things and *who* for people, but in some cases, I can't really explain why, but I'm hesitating between:

> There are 4 more people that have watched the film #2 than people that have watched the film #3.

or

> There are 4 more people who have watched the film #2 than people who have watched the film #3.

or

another way to say it?

Comment: OT: We would just say "film #2", not "the film #2".

Comment: Your second example (using "who") sounds just fine to me, and conforms to the rule. What are you asking for here?

Comment: @EightyEighty I don't know, normally I should use *who*, but I can't explain why, I had an hesitation, thinking that *that* would sound more natural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, so you would confirm the second solution (with who) is correct?